# Move Entry Meta Above Title in Archives (Genesis + Brunch Pro)

Tags: post-meta

I am using Genesis + Brunch Pro, and am attempting to flip the position of the entry title and entry meta in my archives section, so that the date appears before the title: http://simplysamanthablog.com/blog/

*See my home page for how it should look.*

The only thing I've come up with is to switch the positions of the title/meta in the below on settings-archives.php:

```
    $options['archive_show_title'] = array(
    'id'       => 'archive_show_title',
    'label'    => __( 'Display The Title?', 'brunch-pro' ),
    'section'  => $section,
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'default'  => 1,
    'priority' => 5,
);  

$options['archive_show_info'] = array(
    'id'       => 'archive_show_info',
    'label'    => __( 'Display The Entry Info?', 'brunch-pro' ),
    'section'  => $section,
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'default'  => 1,
    'priority' => 6,
);

$options['archive_show_meta'] = array(
    'id'       => 'archive_show_meta',
    'label'    => __( 'Display The Entry Meta?', 'brunch-pro' ),
    'section'  => $section,
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'default'  => 1,
    'priority' => 8,
);
```

However, this does not seem to do anything at all. So I'm stuck.

I'm not sure what other information is needed (I am not very versed in WP coding) so please let me know and I will do my best to provide!

Comment: are you willing to change on the fronted or options menu? The snippet which you posted is of options menu, if you want to change the order there, you can change the priorities.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with "fronted or options menus" ... I'm not very versed in WP coding. If this is not the correct area to make this change, do you happen to know where I am to go?

Comment: you should contact your theme support for this.